# Look of the app - Py2exe / wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe, look-and-feel

So my problem is the look and feel from my application, as it looks like an old look app.

It is an wxPython application, and on python it runs fine and looks fine, but when I convert it to .exe using py2exe, the look is just bad.

Now I know that if you are using XP you need some manifest to correct it but I am in other circumstances. I'm using Windows 7, and I'm using Python 2.6 (Yes, I am including the DLL's and the Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest).

So my question is how can I solve this under these circumstances?

NOTE: I tried to search on google, but the posts I found were rather old with people using XP and older python versions so I assumed it would be different?

EDIT: Screenshots
Normal (wanted look) : http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/3157/70762988.png

Py2exe (unwanted look) : http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/6581/53608742.jpg

Comment: Screenshots would be awesome, you know.

Comment: Normal (wanted look)
http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/3157/70762988.png

             Py2exe (old look)
http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/6581/53608742.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642853/winxp-button-style-with-wxpython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try use [Gui2exe](http://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/)

I use gui2exe on win7 running on virtualbox.

This make gui look ok on all windows version.
upx.exe to compress exe,dll,pyd.

And inno-setup,for a setup fil for windows.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your input! But the reality is, I am in fact, using gui2exe as I am a total newbie to Py2exe.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried with the same config as yesterday but today it worked! Thanks for your help and also, thanks for giving more info on compressing the dlls/pyd